# MoviePy cannot get transparent background in countdown animation

Tags: python, moviepy

For unclear reasons I cannot get a countdown animation to have transparant background.

```
background = ColorClip(size=(W, H), color=(0, 255, 0)).set_opacity(1) #green background

countdownduration = 5            
PartCountDownClip = VideoClip(make_frame=lambda t: TextClip(countdown_text(t), font="Arial", fontsize=450, color='red', stroke_color=StrokeColor, stroke_width=StrokeWidth+5).get_frame(t), duration=countdownduration)

final = CompositeVideoClip([background, testclip.set_duration(countdownduration)])
final = final.set_duration(countdownduration)
output_path = "countdown_animation.mp4"
final.write_videofile(output_path, fps=30, codec='libx264')
```

This generates a blackbox on a green background with a red countdown (5,4,3,2,1)
But when I make:

```
PartCountDownClip = TextClip("test", font="Arial", fontsize=450, color='red', stroke_color=StrokeColor, stroke_width=StrokeWidth+5) #, bg_color='transparent')
```

The result is the word test on a green background. So without the black box! Just like I want it but now there is no counting down, just the word 'test'

So it seems that by the way I make a countdown animation, I cannot get the black box behind the text removed. Why? How to fix? things like adding a bg_color='transparent' do not help.

oh and countdown_text(t) just returns a string from 5 to 1 based in input value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a mask to remove the black box. There is a function `fx.all.mask_color` that creates this mask for a single color based on an existing clip. This masked clip can then be composed with the original background clip.

Code, adapted from https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/389:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx

def countdown_text(t):
    return str(5-int(t))

countdownduration = 5            
W = 800
H = 600
StrokeColor = "red"
StrokeWidth = 5

background = ColorClip(size=(W, H), color=(0, 255, 0)).set_opacity(1) #green background

PartCountDownClip = VideoClip(make_frame=lambda t: TextClip(countdown_text(t), font="Arial", fontsize=450, color='red', stroke_color=StrokeColor, stroke_width=StrokeWidth+5).get_frame(t), duration=countdownduration)

MaskedCountDownClip = vfx.mask_color(PartCountDownClip, color=[0,0,0])

final = CompositeVideoClip([background, MaskedCountDownClip])
final = final.set_duration(countdownduration)
output_path = "countdown_animation.mp4"
final.write_videofile(output_path, fps=30, codec='libx264')
```

Result:

[image]